# How to implement master/slave structure with squeryl and play framework

Tags: scala, playframework, master-slave, squeryl

I am running a play framework website that uses squeryl and mysql database. 
I need to use squeryl to run all read queries to the slave and all write queries to the master.

How can I achieve this? either via squeryl or via jdbc connector itself.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't tend to use MySQL myself, but here's an idea:

Based on the documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-master-slave-replication-connection.html), the MySQL JDBC driver will round robin amongst the slaves if the readOnly attribute is properly set on the Connnection.  In order to retrieve and change the current Connection you'll want to use code like

```
transaction {
  val conn = Session.currentSession.connection
  conn.setReadOnly(true)
  //Your code here
}
```

Even better, you can create your own readOnlyTransaction method:

```
def readOnlyTransaction(f: => Unit) = {
  transaction {
    val conn = Session.currentSession.connection
    val orig = conn.getReadOnly()
    conn.setReadOnly(true)
    f
    conn.setReadOnly(orig)
  }
}
```

Then use it like:

```
readOnlyTransaction {
  //Your code here
}
```

You'll probably want to clean that up a bit so the default readOnly state is reset if an exception occurs, but you get the general idea.

Comment: thanks Dave for ur help. Actually the only problem with such approach is that the separation between read/write operation is done on the developer side to separate read operations from write. I was wondering if we can automate it in a way that it intercept the query itself and decide whether it is a read/write operation? 

The idea is to prevent any human mistake that might happen, since the slaves shouldn't receive any write operation. and the master should handle the write operations only and sync it with slaves.

Comment: In that case, I think you'd really want to do it at the JDBC level.  I don't know if what you're suggesting is a good approach though.  It'll break transaction semantics, since a transaction has to happen on a single connection.  I would hope that setting a connection as readOnly would cause the driver to error out if a developer tries to issue a statement that changes anything, so it may be better to let those errors happen and deal with errors during testing.  Also, keep in mind that "select for update" exists so you can't rely on a select never changing anything.